# The dual of this SDP with a simple nonconvex constraint

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, non-convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

In this problem we're optimizing over variables $X\in \text{PSD}_n$ and $Y\in\mathbb R^{d\times n}$ for some $d\le n$.
\begin{align}
    &\text{Maximize}&&\langle A_0, Z\rangle\\
    &\text{Subject to}&&\langle A_i, Z\rangle\le b_i\\
   &&&Z=\begin{bmatrix}X & Y^T\\
                       Y & I
\end{bmatrix}\succeq 0\\
&&&\text{Trace}(X)=\Vert  Y\Vert_F^2.
\end{align}

The Lagrangian is $$L(X,Y; W, \alpha,\lambda)=-\sum_i\alpha_ib_i+\langle A_0-W, Z\rangle + \sum_{i}\alpha_i\langle A_i, Z\rangle + \lambda(\text{Trace}(X)-\Vert Y\Vert_F^2).$$

Then I get that $$g(\alpha, \lambda)=\min_{X,Y}L(X, Y, \alpha, \lambda)=\begin{cases}-\sum_i\alpha_ib_i+\min_{X,Y}\lambda(\text{Trace}(X)-\Vert Y\Vert_F^2)& \text{if } A_0+\sum_i\alpha_iA_i\succeq 0\\
-\infty&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Of course, it's the last constraint that's giving me trouble. I tried putting it into a nicer form so that I could possibly include into the PSD constraint in the dual:
$$\text{Trace}(X)-\Vert Y\Vert_F^2=\left\langle
\begin{bmatrix}
    X&Y^T\\
Y&0
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
I&-Y^T/2\\
-Y/2&0
\end{bmatrix}
\right\rangle=0,$$

but this ends up not helping at all (as far as I can see). Is there a way to find a nice form of the dual of the above program?

Comment: How does your Lagrangian incorporate the $Z \ge 0$ constraint?

Comment: Oops, it didn't. I added the matrix variable $W$ in $L$. I think $g$ should remain the same though, as we need $A_0 + \sum_i\alpha_iA_i\succeq W$. If we restrict $W$ to equal the left-hand side, then  we just need the left-hand side to be PSD.